# What's the missing character: 幼儿为「么？」?

Tags: character-identification

I've got this horrible scan from《旅行雜志》1945年第7期，第8頁 and I'm trying to make out the characters:

> [image]

What I've got so far:

幼儿为「么？」

Any idea what the missing character is?

A logical answer would be: 兒, but it doesn't really look like that.

Comment: please show the whole sentence or paragraph. Such little information is not difficult even to natives :)

Comment: @TooskyHierot That's the whole sentence. The article is just filled with short bursts of info like: 夫妻名为「两口子」& 乡人称妻为「屋里」。If you really want to see the full section, it's here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jnLL.png - but I don't think it's going to help much with answering this question because like I mentioned, it's a really horrible scan.

Comment: I feel it like 幼敘為「幺〇」

Comment: Sometimes 么 is used as an alternative form of 幺, which means youngest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a list of 四川話 (Sichuan dialect) terms, I suppose it showed other provinces' visitors some basic terms in Sichuan  dialect

It includes :

夫妻為 「兩口子」(husband and wife is "兩口子")

最小兒女為「么兒」(smallest child is "么兒")

小妹妺為「么妺」; 「么姑娘」(youngest sister is "么妺" ; "么姑娘"

小弟弟為「么兄弟」(youngest brother is "么兄弟")

The one sentence you are asking is:

> 幼叔為「么叔」(youngest uncle is "么叔" )

The  Chinese 「  mark below 为  bent left instead of bent right, because the text was written in vertical right to left Chinese style.

I bet Sichuan dialect speakers can guess the missing characters better than Mandarin speakers. I couldn't figure out 「屋里」 in 男人稱妻人為「屋里」(men call their wives as "屋里")